# iReport : How to process a parameter whose expression class = List and inside that list is another list?

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports

I have a parameter whose expression class is a List. Inside that List is another list so the data looks something like this.

```
Class Bean{

String property1
String property2
Long property3
List<BeanDetails> beanDetails
}
```

Please take note that I'll be passing Bean in a list. (List beans)

1) Is it possible to process and read this type of data in iReport?

2) How are we going to declare it/ define it and use it in iReport?

The report should look like this

```
Col1    Col2     Col3       Col4              Col5              Col6    
 1     bean.id  bean.name   beanDetail.det1   beanDetail.det2   beanDetail.det3
                            beanDetail.det1   beanDetail.det2   beanDetail.det3
                            beanDetail.det1   beanDetail.det2   beanDetail.det3

 2     bean.id  bean.name   beanDetail.det1   beanDetail.det2   beanDetail.det3
                            beanDetail.det1   beanDetail.det2   beanDetail.det3
                            beanDetail.det1   beanDetail.det2   beanDetail.det3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to achieve what you need.

1. Create **flat** structure of your datasource, as example a `List` of `Map<String,Object>`, looping your `Bean`, `BeanDetails` example

   ```
   List<Map<String,Object>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
   for(Bean bean : yourBeans){
     Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
     map.put("col1", bean.getProperty1());
     map.put("col2", bean.getProperty2());
     map.put("col3", bean.getProperty3());
     boolean first = true;
     if (bean.getBeanDetails()==null|| bean.getBeanDetails().size()==0){
       mapList.add(map);
     }else{
      for (BeanDetails bd:bean.getBeanDetails()){
        if (!first){
            map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map."col1", "");//or use printWhenExpression != null in jrxml
            ....
        }else{
           first = false;
        }
        map.put("col4",bd.getDet1());
        ....
        mapList.add(map);
     }
    }
   }
   //This now becomes your datasource
   JRMapArrayDataSource datasource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(mapList);
   ```
2. Use **subreport** include a subreport spanning col4 to col6, setup field `Bean` in main report

   ```
   <field name="_THIS" class="com.your.package.Bean"/>
   ```

   and pass as datasource to the subreport

   ```
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{_THIS}.getBeanDetails())]]></dataSourceExpression>
   ```
3. Create you own **JRDataSource** (I will not submit the whole class, but only some hints on how this can be done, creating a new class implementing `JRDataSource`)

   ```
   JRDataSource myDatasource = new JRDataSource() {
       //TODO: keep controll of you list of Beans, current Bean and current BeanDetails, using pointers.
       @Override
       public boolean next() throws JRException {
        //TODO: Implement if there are still records, move to next Bean or BeanDetails
        boolean existsRecords = false;
        return existsRecords;
       }

       @Override
       public Object getFieldValue(JRField field) throws JRException {
          String name = field.getName();
          //TODO: On the basis of your pointer, current Bean and current BeanDetails, return the value requested.
          return null;
       }
   };
   ```

Make your choice and have fun!

Comment: Hi, @PetterFriberg I followed your solution 1 (but I did not copy your code). I've already displayed the data but not like the one showed above. I've  added an "id" property and my plan was to create a groupheader and group them by id but it didn't work. Could you tell me how to display the data like table shown above? Thank you.

Comment: You do no need to group to achieve the result above. To remove col1-col3 the solutions depends on what you put in the hashmap. 1) Put null, nothing use printWhenExpression, 2) Put empty "", do nothing, 3) Put same as primary record, use isPrintRepeatedValues="false" on reportElement

Comment: If you still have problems, I suggest you open another question, with the jrxml, the datasource, the current output and desired output.

Comment: Hi @PeterFriberg and to all readers. printWhenExpression did the trick. Thank  you :)

Comment: you will see printWhenExpression property in the textfield. put something like this "$V{groupById_COUNT} == 1" groupById is a group.